# Nested Array to return a sum and each amount based on 2 criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I trying to create a formula that will return a series of values.

I would like to return the following in one column.  If the criteria is not met, I would like to move to the next search item and not return a zero.

The sum of column A ONLY IF column F is "Y" AND Column J is "ABC".
The sum of column B ONLY IF column G is "Y" AND Column J is "ABC".
The sum of column C ONLY IF column H is "Y" AND Column J is "ABC".
Each value in column D ONLY IF column I is "Y" AND Column J is "ABC".

I believe I need to use a nested array but not sure.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Currently, I am using the below which only returns all of the values in column D but I'm not sure how to pull the sums from columns A, B and C (if they meet the criteria)

```
=NUMBERVALUE(INDEX('IMS Import'!$I$4:$AB$5000,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($X$4, 'IMS Import'!$Z$4:$Z$5000)*COUNTIF($X$3, 'IMS Import'!$AB$4:$AB$5000), ROW('IMS Import'!$I$4:$AB$5000)-MIN(ROW('IMS Import'!$I$4:$AB$5000))+1), ROW(A2)), COLUMN(A2)))
```

Comment: 4 SUMIFS summed together

Comment: There is no need for nested arrays, but for nested functions. Each line of your assertion is the ELSE of the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!  I am not trying to return the sum of all 4 columns, so the 4 sumifs do not work.

Comment: I need to use an array to step through each value in column in column D, correct?  I believe I need to use another array to step through column A, B and C.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,F:F,"Y",J:J,"ABC")
+SUMIFS(B:B,G:G,"Y",J:J,"ABC")
+SUMIFS(C:C,H:H,"Y",J:J,"ABC")
+SUMIFS(D:D,I:I,"Y",J:J,"ABC")
```